# Casting signed and unsigned numbers

Tags: c

I had a function that was producing invalid input when dividing a signed number by an unsigned number. What this means is that the negative number was being interpreted as `unsigned` and so was making a calculation invalid. For example, here are the possibilities when dividing between two potentially signed numbers:

```
printf ("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",
        (signed)10 / (signed)8,
        (unsigned)10 / (signed)8,
        (unsigned)10 / (unsigned)8,
        
        (signed)-10 / (signed)8,
        (unsigned)-10 / (signed)8,       // bad result
        (unsigned)-10 / (unsigned)8,     // bad result
        
        (signed)-10 / (signed)-8,
        (unsigned)-10 / (signed)-8,     // ??
        (unsigned)-10 / (unsigned)-8    // ??
);
```

---

```
$ run
// 1 1 1 -1 536870910 536870910 1 0 0
```

What are the rules for when a `signed` number is divided by an `unsigned` number? Are both numbers cast to the same type before the calculation? Or is the result cast? It seems in the function I had a signed negative number that was being divided by an unsigned positive number, which I thought would "just work", but it seems them instead of the types being implicitly converted so that my number would be, for example, "-1", the result came out to be a very large positive number. What are the rules when mixed-sign numbers are operated on?

Comment: This is all undefined behaviour. The placeholders must match the type used, so `%d` vs. `%u`. Casting a signed to an unsigned and falling out of bounds is also, I believe, undefined behaviour. `-10` cannot be represented as `unsigned`.

Comment: @tadman `signed/signed` results in `signed`, so `%d` should be defined behavior, no?

Comment: @tadman casting signed to unsigned is well defined, it uses modular arithmetic. The problem is going the other way if the unsigned value is outside the range of the signed.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings to be sure (`-Wall`). Several of these are `unsigned`.

Comment: @Barmar Is it implementation defined, or standard defined? This looks like an underflow which normally "wraps" though I'm not sure if that's specified behaviour.

Comment: @tadman Standard-defined: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2

Comment: @Barmar Very illuminating. Thanks!

Comment: (4294967295 - 10) / 8 = 536870910, you underflow your unsigned int so thats why

Comment: `(unsigned)-10 / (signed)-8,` this one is interesting, I would have expected something else

Comment: The answer to the original question is in the standard's section on [usual arithmetic conversion](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8), in the bullet about integer promotions.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for sharing that. Would you want to post an answer that is a bit more readable / understandable for a non-C expert that perhaps shines some light on what the standard says (and maybe an example showing it)?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL what does "underflow" mean? Does that mean something like converting `-1` 's bitpattern to what it would look be interpreted as signed (that is, a very large number) ?

Comment: I'm putting it off in the hopes that someone else will know a duplicate that this can be linked to, since I'm sure questions like this have been asked before.

Comment: @tadman why would `(signed)10 / (signed)8`, `(unsigned)10 / (signed)8`, `(unsigned)10 / (unsigned)8`, and `(signed)-10 / (signed)-8`, and `(signed)-10 / (signed)8` be undefined behavior? Or do you just mean the ones in my question that I commented?

Comment: I mean the presentation part specifically. Barmar helpfully clarified the behaviour of the underflow. `%u` != `%d`.

Comment: Overflow and underflow result when an operation involving signed types results in a value outside the range of the type. E.g. `INT_MAX + 1` and `INT_MIN - 1`. Or `(signed) UINT_MAX`

Comment: @Barmar I see, on a tangent to that, do you know if both are handled by the `OVERFLOW` flag in x86, or are there two different flags for it?

Comment: I don't think the hardware overflow flag has anything to do with this. C doesn't require overflow/underflow to be detected, and most implementations will simply wrap around (so `INT_MAX + 1 == INT_MIN`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each of arguments, three things happen in this order:

1. The conversions specified by the casts are performed.
2. The two operands of `/` are converted to a common type.
3. The argument is passed to `printf` to be converted to text by `%d`.

Let’s discuss these in order.

### 1. Casts and Conversions

A conversion is a change of value from one type to another. Where possible, a conversion does not change the value. Otherwise, we desire conversions to change the value as little as possible (converting 3.125 from `float` to `int` produces 3, not 87) or in some information-preserving way (conversions from a 32-bit `int` to a 32-bit `unsigned int` “wrap” modulo 2<sup>32</sup>).

Some conversions occur automatically. For example, in `int x = 3.125f;`, the `float` value 3.125 is converted to the `int` value 3.

To explicitly request a conversion, we use a cast. A cast operator has the form  `(type) expression`. A cast is specifically this operator. Automatic conversions are not casts.

When a signed integer with value *x* is converted to an *n*-bit unsigned integer, the result is, the result is what you get by taking *x* and adding or subtracting 2<sup>*n*</sup> until you get a value that is representable in the unsigned integer type. For example, when −10 is converted to a 32-bit `unsigned int`, 2<sup>32</sup> (4,294,967,296) is added once, producing −10 + 4,294,967,296 = 4,294,967,286. When −8 is converted, the result is −8 + 4,294,967,296 = 4,294,967,288.

These both had to add 2<sup>32</sup> just once to bring the value in range. To see an example where multiple additions or subtractions are necessary, consider converting 1001 to eight-bit `unsigned char`. The three subtractions of 256 are necessary to bring the result into the range 0 to 255, so the result is 1001 − 3•256 = 1001 − 768 = 233.

### 2. The Usual Arithmetic Conversions

For many C binary operators, particularly the arithmetic operators, the two operands are converted to a common type perform the operation is performed. (This is largely due to how computer hardware works; it is easy to multiply two unsigned numbers or two signed numbers but somewhat awkward to multiply a signed number by an unsigned number.) The rules for this are called the *usual arithmetic conversions*.

For example, the specification for the `/` operator in C 2018 6.5.5 3 says “The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.” The usual arithmetic conversions are specified in C 2018 6.3.1.8. The rules are expressed with a technical concept of rank and other details but may be summarized for standard real types: If either operand is earlier in the list below than `int`, it is converted to `int`. (This part is called the *integer promotions*.) After that, if the two operand types are different, the operand with the earlier type is converted to the later type:

- `_Bool`, `signed char`, `char`, `unsigned char`, `short`, `unsigned short`, `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`, `float`, `double`, `long double`.

Here is how this affects your examples, demonstrated with a 32-bit `int` (a.k.a. `signed`) and a 32-bit `unsigned` (a.k.a. `unsigned int`):

- `(signed)10 / (signed)8`. Both operands are `int`. 10/8 is computed, and the result is 1.
- `(unsigned)10 / (signed)8`. `(signed)8` is converted to `unsigned`, which does not change the value. 10/8 is computed, and the result is 1.
- `(unsigned)10 / (unsigned)8`. Both operands are `unsigned int`. 10/8 is computed, and the result is 1.
- `(signed)-10 / (signed)8`. Both operands are `int`. −10/8 is computed, and the result is −1.
- `(unsigned)-10 / (signed)8`. `(unsigned)-10` is 4,294,967,286. `(signed)8` is converted to `unsigned int`, which does not change the value. 4,294,967,286/8 is computed, and the result is 536,870,910.
- `(unsigned)-10 / (unsigned)8`. `(unsigned)-10` is 4,294,967,286. Both perands are `unsigned int`. 4,294,967,286/8 is computed, and the result is 536,870,910.
- `(signed)-10 / (signed)-8`. Both operands are `int`. −10/−8 is computed, and the result is 1.
- `(unsigned)-10 / (signed)-8`. `(unsigned)-10` is 4,294,967,286. `(signed)−8` is converted to `unsigned int`, which changes the value to 4,294,967,288. 4,294,967,286/4,294,967,288 is computed, and the result is 0.
- `(unsigned)-10 / (unsigned)-8`. `(unsigned)-10` is 4,294,967,286. `(unsigned)−8` is 4,294,967,288. 4,294,967,286/4,294,967,288 is computed, and the result is 0.

### 3. `printf` Conversion Specifiers

The result of the division operator, `/`, has the same type as the operands after the usual arithmetic conversions. So some of your arguments have type `int`, and some have type `unsigned int`.

When `%d` is used in the `printf` format, the corresponding argument is supposed to be an `int`. This is specified in C 2018 7.21.6.1 8 (which is about `fprintf`, but the `fprintf` clause refers to it). Paragraph 9 says “… If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.”

So, formally, the behavior of your program is not defined by the C standard. However, C implementations often let this substitution of an `unsigned int` argument for an `int` argument slide, and the program “works” due to a combination of historical reasons and how software and hardware work. (This substitution is explicitly allowed when calling a function declared without a prototype, in C 2018 6.5.2.2 6. One might argue that if you did not include `<stdio.h>` and declared `printf` yourself with `int printf();`, it would be allowed by that rule.)

So, in spite of having behavior not defined by the C standard, it is unsurprising your program prints the results described above. However, it would be better to change `%d` to `%u` for the cases where the argument is `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

With `(unsigned)-10`, what you get at compilation is `4294967295 (uint32_t max value, due to the underflow), minus 10`, then divided by 8, which is indeed 536870910.

As for your different divisions, the result is [standard defined](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2) (credit @Barmar)